# Tutorial uses a React Hook, but I'm working in a Class Component setting

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, google-analytics

I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](https://dev.to/basileleroy/google-analytics-on-react-js-components-4d2a) to implement Google Analytics with pageview tracking in my React application. However, the tutorial uses a React hook, while I've set up my application using class components. I've unsuccesful to translate the tuturial to a class setting. How should I adjust to make this work for my use case?

Routes page, \src\pages\index.js:

```
// the function of concern
import useGaTracker from "../useGaTracker";

class Base extends Component {
    render() {
        useGaTracker();
        // The hook inside a Class component, which is not allowed.
        // But how can I make it work in my class components setting?

        function withProps(Component, props) {
            return function (matchProps) {
                return <Component {...props} {...matchProps} />;
            };
        }

        return (
            <Router history={history}>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={Homepage} />
                    // Etc.
```

GA function, \src\useGaTracker.js:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import ReactGA from "react-ga";

const useGaTracker = () => {
    const location = useLocation();
    const [initialized, setInitialized] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        ReactGA.initialize(process.env.REACT_APP_GA_TAG);
        setInitialized(true);
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (initialized) {
            ReactGA.pageview(window.location.pathname + window.location.search);
        }
    }, [initialized, location]);
};

export default useGaTracker;
```

And \src\index.js:

```
import Base from "./pages";

render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Base />
        </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Calling upon the GA function inside he Base class produces the error:

> Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body
> of a function component.

How should I rewrite this to make it work in my Class components setting?

Comment: "Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component." — You've written a class component not a function component.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Tools_and_testing/Client-side_JavaScript_frameworks/React_getting_started#exploring_our_first_react_component_%E2%80%94_app

Comment: Thanks @Quentin, how should I correct that? Should I perhaps add `useGaTracker();` to `src/index.js` instead of `src/pages/index.js`? What should that look like?

Comment: I know this isn't what you want to hear, but functional components and hooks are much much better than class components and it's worth the time to learn them. You can also have a mix of functional and class components - they can work together. Don't get bogged down by some idea that all components have to be the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make a higher-order component create a functional component, and have that one call `useGaTracker` before rendering the given non-functional Component:

```
const withGaTracker = (Component) => {
  return (props) => {
    useGaTracker();
    return (
      <Component {...props} />
    );
  };
};
```

Then pass in the `Base` component

```
const BaseWithGaTracker = withGaTracker(Base);
```

and render the result in your index.js by replacing `<Base />` with  `<BaseWithGaTracker />`.

---

edit: Simpler yet, just make a single functional component that calls the hook and renders its children:

```
const GaTracker = ({children}) => {
  useGaTracker();
  return children;
}
```

then wrap that around `<Base />` in index.js

```
<GaTracker>
  <Base />
</GaTracker>
```

If you're not gonna use that hook anywhere else, you could also just inline it in the new component.

Comment: Ah, thanks @daniero, I'm indeed not using that hook anywhere else. How would doing this inline look like?

Comment: NP. A hook is (almost) just a function, so by inlining I just meant replacing the call to `useGaTracker()` with the content of that function. Doesn't really matter much though.

Comment: Thanks! It works great like this!